# Stay logged in through a PHP discord oauth2 (cookie?)

Tags: php, authentication, cookies, oauth-2.0, discord

I am working on a site that involves logging in through discord, which uses oauth2. I believe the login is controlled by the phpsessid cookie, from what i can tell. My problem is this cookie resets when the browser is closed, meaning whenever the browser closes, the user has to log back in.

I was wondering if there was a way to keep the session running even after closing the browser, or maybe a different method to keep the user logged in? I found the PHP function `session_set_cookie_params()` that could be useful, but I'm not sure how I can use this in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

In order to store data even if you close the browser, you need to use cookies. With PHP, you need to use the [`setcookie()`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.setcookie.php) method.

Default example:

```php
<?php
 setcookie('yourCookieName', "yourCookieValue");
?>
```

Another example:

```php
<?php
 setcookie('yourCookieName', "yourCookieValue", time() + 365*24*3600, '/', '.yourdomain.com');
?>
```

I have added some parameters as time and a way to keep the cookie for all the website subdomains.

And then, if you can get the cookie with `$_COOKIE['yourCookieName']`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use javascript to acces that cookie and then save it as a new cookie on your website,and then load it when the user connects.Look on w3school javascript cookies